# Redirect::to NotfoundHttpException Error

Tags: laravel-4

In the controller if I write

```
return Redirect::to('admin/createpost');
```

It throws `NotfoundHttpException` when redirecting. But if i use just

```
return Redirect::to('createpost')
```

It is working fine. I guess it accesses my intended view( admin/createpost) via this route

```
Route::get('createpost', 'AdminController@getCreate');
```

In the first case, why it throws error. What is the correct way to use `Redirect::to`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Redirect::to` is the exact url you want to go to.

So if you want to make your route '`admin/createpost`' change

```
Route::get('createpost', 'AdminController@getCreate');
```

to

```
Route::get('admin/createpost', 'AdminController@getCreate');
```

Comment: So to use Redirect::to('admin/createpost'), Should i have the route 'admin/createpost'? When i changed, i got error that no named route exists. So I used name routing. Still have the error  MethodNotAllowedHttpException. My named routes 'Route::get('admin/createpost',array('as' => 'admin/createpost', 'uses'=>'AdminController@getCreate'));
 Route::post('admin/createpost', array('as'=> 'admin/createpost','uses'=>'AdminController@postCreate'));
'.